# How to link social media in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to generate PDF from HTML and want to append social media link in the PDF file. I have tried to add using link and image like this:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js" ></script>
<div id="customers">
<table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="15%">
            <col width="15%">
                <col width="15%">
                    <col width="15%">
                        <col width="15%">
                            <col width="25%">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class='warning'>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Peril</th>
            <th>Std Dev</th>
            <th>Expected Loss</th>
            <th>1% (100 yrs) TVAR</th>
            <th>4% (250 yrs) TVAR</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>All Region</td>
            <td>All Peril</td>
            <td>1,363,480,000</td>
            <td>10,907,648,067</td>
            <td>10,907,648,067</td>
            <td>10,907,648,067</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NA_CUSTOM (CUSTOM)</td>
            <td>Earthquake</td>
            <td>100,363,480,000</td>
            <td>10,907,648,067</td>
            <td>10,907,648,067</td>
            <td>10,907,648,067</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>All</td>
            <td>All</td>
            <td>1,363</td>
            <td>10,907</td>
            <td>10,907</td>
            <td>907.32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NA_CUSTOM</td>
            <td>EQ</td>
            <td>1,363</td>
            <td>10,907</td>
            <td>10,907</td>
            <td>907.32</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function demoFromHTML() {
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
// source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
// to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
source = $('#customers')[0];
var f_icon='data:image/jpeg;base64,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';

// we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
// ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
// There is no support for any other type of selectors 
// (class, of compound) at this time.
specialElementHandlers = {
    // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
        // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
        return true
    }
};
margins = {
    top: 80,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 10,
    width: 700
};
// all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
// 'inches' in this case
pdf.fromHTML(
source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
margins.left, // x coord
margins.top, { // y coord
    'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
},

function (dispose) {
    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
    pdf.setFontSize(3);
    pdf.text(35, 25, "http://www.google.com");
   //pdf.addImage(f_icon, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
    pdf.save('Test.pdf');
  }, margins);
 }
```

The [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugD5L/278/) is here. I am not been able to add hyperlink in the PDF for social media.